# Setting up MySite on single machine without AD?

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync, my-site

We are developing on single machine without AD role, because we thought that since we are going to use ADFS, we don't need it. Our project requires that we set up MySite for users. I'm struggling with this, since I can't get "User Profile Synchronization Service" to start. Now I think that it might be connected with fact, that I don't have an AD instance.

I used most of the tutorials and walkthroughs about setting MySite and profile synchronization, but neither was sufficient.

I also read probably most of the User Profile Synchronization Service "Starting" Issue, but that didn't work either. So I'd like to know if it is even possible to run MySite and profile synchronization on single machine. Because if it's not possible, I'll stop trying and wasting my time.

Comment: It works on my machine (without AD) - so it is possible :)
A system engineer set up my environment, so I can't give you advice about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [workarounds](http://www.dev4side.com/community/blog/2010/5/2/how-to-install-sharepoint-2010-with-a-local-account.aspx) to utilize local account when installing on Win7, but you wont want to do that in a production because:

1. you wont be supported by Microsoft
2. your farm wont scale
3. you can count on having weird issues that you will most likely not
   find documentation on.

In order for you to setup synchronization, when you configure the sync you need to specify the authentication provider type and instance.  If your provider is not listed then it is most likely not configured correctly.

I recommend going thru [Spence Harbars guide](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx), and his associated posts.  He doesn't delve into Claims/FBA but has a ton of info on how UPS works, and the requirements for it work (permissions, configuration, etc).  [Shannon Bray](http://shannonbray.wordpress.com/), also has informative information on FBA and MySites.

Of course [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx) article should be reviewed as well.  Althought it doesn't call out FBA, the steps for eDirectory are simliar (as it requires FBA).

Based on your current setup, you dont have a firm grasp on how SharePoint should be deployed and its topologies.  I would read pretty much every entry under the [deployment category](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957.aspx) on TechNet or for an easier read grab a good [admin book](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=sharepoint%202010%20administration&x=0&y=0&sprefix=Unified%20access).  If deployed without proper planning, I can promise you will have issues later, and at some point make managing it a chore.

Comment: After some reading I think I'll have to reinstall whole platform since Spence Harbar advises perform actions on clean sharepoint and my is quite stuffed.